How to check if the credentials entered match those in the database for that specific user
Here is the code, I'm not sure how to check that the password entered is the correct one associated with the email in the database. I tried making a password variable but that just checks if any account has that password
@app.route('/login-submission-form', methods=['GET'])
def loginUser():
    email = request.form["login-email"]
    user = User.query.filter_by(email=email)

    if email:
        # check if the password associated with the email is correct


It's almost impossible to understand your question. Why do you think that for user in User.db should "be the route"?

just an idea but if you could provide  a solution that'd help. My questions is how can I check if the email and password entered by the user matches that of any account with the database.

But what's unclear is what you're actually asking. Are you using flask-login?. user = User.query.filter_by(email=email) returns the User object (if you set it up correctly) and then you compare passwords (hashed!) after that

Honestly, I think User.query.filter_by(email=email) returns the query, which should be completed with .first() to get only one user. The password hash should then be compared with the user input like @roganjosh mentioned.

done that however i get presented with an operational error

You could do like this:
from werkzeug.security import check_password_hash


@app.route('/login-submission-form', methods=['GET'])
def loginUser():
    email = request.form["login-email"]
    password = request.form.get("login-password")
    

    if email and password:
        user = User.query.filter_by(email=email).first()
        if user:
            # Check if the hashed password matches the provided password
            if check_password_hash(user.password, password):
                return "Login successful"
            else:
                return "Incorrect password"
        else:
            return "User not found"
    else:
        return "Invalid email or password"


You shouldn't disclose whether it was the username or password that was incorrect - it's better to give a blanket "username or password not recognised" message for both errors. Telling a hacker that it was their username or password leaks info for them to use

@roganjosh It's just an example code. You can put whatever message you want to.

I was thrown an operational error to do with the user = user.query.filter by  line

Can you share the operational error that you are facing ? @JadoreThompson

sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table: users
[SQL: SELECT users.id AS users_id, users.username AS users_username, users.email AS users_email, users.password AS users_password
FROM users
WHERE users.username = ?
LIMIT ? OFFSET ?]
[parameters: ('zenz', 1, 0)]
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/e3q8)

I fixed it, was being too lazy to search up . just had to do db.createall()
